# Access a file from different Directory

Tags: java, swing, usb

I am working with a Java Application. In this, I must copy a file from source to Multiple Destinations. The destinations are various USB drives. (ie) I'm copying a file for desktop and sending to a number of USB drives. Here, my problem is, I am sending files to all USB drives I attached, now I need to make the files UN-deletable. The undeletable process will be done in a single event. For example once I click the ok button, the Files, which are present in all USB drives are made undeletable. Any idea how to do this.

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7282901/undeletable-folder-in-java) may help you for creating un-deletable folders and files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When copying source file to other files, put the destination `File` objects in a collection. Then, in the event handler for your 'set read only' button, loop over that collection and call [`setReadOnly()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#setReadOnly%28%29) on each File.

Comment: same time,i must do it for all files located in different USB drives

Answer (score 0):

not very sure I understand your question correctly.

maybe you can store the directories and when you click the OK button, you iterate these directories and set them to undeletable one by one?

Comment: Yes, (* the files i same but it is located in different drives eg. H:,I:,J:...etc)