# Create a File that cannot be deleted Java

Tags: java, file

Hi guys I am Using CreateNewFile() function to make a .txt file I them Hide it using the Following Code In System32 Directory.

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("attrib +h " + f.getPath());
p.waitFor();
```

The File is getting Hidden successfully But I need it to be secure so that you cannot delete it even if you wanted to. Is there a way to achieve this Programmatically?

Comment: btw, you can set file attributes using java 7 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664432/how-do-i-programmatically-change-file-permissions

Comment: @Wookie88, if you believe the answer to that, I'm going to need your username and password to paypal in order to approve that comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`I don't think so` You can do it. Every file can be deleted somehow in windows(booting in safe mode).

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to use `Username` while creating File. `You can not delete file created by other user unless you are administrative.`

You will find More information [Undeletable Folder in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7282901/undeletable-folder-in-java)